# Output List parameter is not modified after exiting a function in C#

Tags: c#

I having a problem with output parameter in C#

I have the following function:

```
public Financial Calculate(int dealerPricingID, int customerID, bool dealerPriceChanged, bool saving, int specialBidID, int promotionID, List<Item> outItems)
```

The parameter outItems is an output parameter and before calling the function I just initialize it with

```
var items = new List<Item>();
```

I thought that since a list is a reference type it should end up modified after the function is executed (in the function the list is filled with Item objects that are affected in the calculation). However, it stays unmodified and after debugging I see that inside the function items are add to the collection it just returns empty.

It seems I have some of my concepts of C# wrong, so why is this not working in this situation?

Comment: It certainly should work. What are you not showing us?

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the correct list? and that after the execution of the method you are checking the right list? can I see where the call to the method Calculate is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't re-initialized `outItems` inside `Calculate`, have you? If you just modify the elements, it should work fine. If you assign another `List<Item>` to `outItems`, you modify the *reference* which is *copied*.

```
public Financial Calculate(List<Item> outItems)
{
  outItems.Add(new Item()); // fine
  return new Financial();
}

public Financial Calculate(List<Item> outItems)
{
  outItems = new List<Item>(); // wrong!
  outItems.Add(new Item());
  return new Financial();
}
```

If you want to pass a reference to the reference, use the `ref` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialised the List<>?

Also it's a good idea to add the out keyword as it helps the readability and enforces functionality required.

```
List<MyT> myList = new List<MyT>();
Caclulate(..., out myList);

...

public void Calculate(... , out List<MyT> aList)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is perhaps an improvement indeed, or maybe a change of the method's name. `Calculate` as a name doesn't emphasize that a passed list is changed. An `out` parameter would.